# C# Listbox selecting items

Tags: c#, winforms

my For statement is not highlighting/selecting items from the listbox am missing something?

```
    if (listId.Items.Count != 0 && listCell.Items.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < listId.Items.Count; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < listCell.Items.Count; b++)
            {
                MakeReq(txtWebUpdate.Text + listId.Items[a].ToString() + 
                "&brand=1", listCell.Items[b].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

this is an old vb6 code i dug up that i use to use... what it did was loop through a listbox select one entry at a time and also highlighted/selected visually the entry in the listbox. I want to do something just like that with the C# code above

```
Do Until lstNames.ListCount = 0
  lstNames.ListIndex = 0

  GetMoreNames = ""

  For b = 1 To 1
    GetMoreNames = GetMoreNames & lstNames.Text & ","
    lstNames.RemoveItem lstNames.ListIndex
    lstNames.ListIndex = lstNames.ListIndex + 1
  Next b
```

Comment: What are listId and listCell, and how do they relate to each other?  I would expect that you'd need to relate the two somehow for the inner loop to work correctly.

Comment: @acctman, have you tried adding a break point on your for loop, to see whats happening in side of it?

Comment: What are you using? ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: @Robotsushi it's a function i created to pass the values over to another function. that part works fine. Am I suppose to be using the .Select property for the listboxs?

Comment: @Tim listID are productID numbers and listCell are various placement locations. I need to loop though ListID selecting 1 ID at a time and then also loop though listCell selecting one location... The catch is listCell needs to continue to loop there is only 33 locations and listID has 300+ IDs. so listID process the entire list once, while listCell just keeps looping giving a location to each ID.

Comment: @Jethro I think I have two problems 1. i think I should be using the .Select Property to get a visual selecting of each item. and 2. my second loop for listCell might be wrong (see comment to Tim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the makeReq is redirecting with a querystring value? Need more code to know see what you're trying to accomplish here.

I don't know why you wouldn't just use a simple ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value;

Comment: makeReq is pretty simple... its definitely not the problem, at least I dont think so. this is all that it's doing then its used as a function.

void MakeReq(string Url, string Cell) { webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(Url)); txtCellRecord.txt = Cell; }

Comment: How would I use the SelectItem.Value property? do it take the place of listId.Items[a].ToString()

Comment: Yes, if you have the data value field set for the listbox. There is also a datatext property of the listbox you could use as well.